# can't execute sphinx search command not found

Tags: search, terminal, sphinx, opensuse

I have an Opensuse 13.2 operating system. Also I installed sphinx search engine. Everything was great till I tried to execute search command in terminal.

```
search: command not found
```

Before that I configured sphinx, executed indexer, executed searchd, all good.

Here is searchd output command:

```
vitalik-opensuse:/home/vitalik # searchd 
Sphinx 2.2.8-id64-release (rel22-r4942)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc(http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
listening on all interfaces, port=9306
precaching index 'deal'
precaching index 'deal-have'                                
precaching index 'deal-want'                                
precached 3 indexes in 0.086 sec
```

Here is indexer output:

```
vitalik-opensuse:/home/vitalik # indexer --all
Sphinx 2.2.8-id64-release (rel22-r4942)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'deal'...
collected 7 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 7 docs, 1355 bytes
total 0.021 sec, 62708 bytes/sec, 323.95 docs/sec
indexing index 'deal-have'...
collected 7 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 7 docs, 1355 bytes
total 0.007 sec, 193240 bytes/sec, 998.28 docs/sec
indexing index 'deal-want'...
collected 7 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 7 docs, 1355 bytes
total 0.006 sec, 207758 bytes/sec, 1073.29 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'dist1'...
total 12 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.8 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 36 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.4 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

But I still can't execute search command to try searching via terminal.
Sphinx version is 2.2.8, installed from 
[opensuse-13.2-server-search-repository](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/search/openSUSE_13.2/x86_64/)
What I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `search` tool no longer exists.  It was removed a few versions ago.

Its long been broken, and not a realistic search experience.

Use test.php etc from the api folder to test searchd.